# How to auto update app with apk file downloaded from an url?

Tags: android, flutter

I want to auto update app with an apk file downloaded from an url. I know it's not security but my app only using for a group only but having many devices so I don't want to install it manually for every device.

I have tried to use this package: [opta_update](https://pub.dev/packages/ota_update#-readme-tab-) but nothing happened when i run it and others way but seem like it only work for rooted device.

Update: my device can't not reach Play Store since it have to connect a wifi with private proxy.

Comment: as far as i know, only system app or root devices can do this stuff

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android programmatically update application when a new version is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22709443/android-programmatically-update-application-when-a-new-version-is-available) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575046/force-app-to-update-when-new-version-of-app-is-available-in-android-play-store , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466516/notify-user-within-app-that-a-new-version-is-available , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296491/how-to-force-update-in-android-application-if-new-version-is-available/57072102

Comment: @InsaneCat thanks for reply my question. Sorry but all the devices can't reach play store since the private proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an `internal` Play store beta deployment track. Add list of users to the testers list. Every time you upload a new APK, if the users have automated updates on, they get a fresh build updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply my question. I can upload it to playstore but all the device have to use the wifi with private proxy for security so the device can't reach the playstore

Comment: That’s quite stringent requirement. I guess you should update that in your question!

Answer (score 0):

1) If App is not on Play Store

You can use Push Notification and Sent a message to all users to update the latest version of App

OR

2) If App is on Play Store

You can also write code in the main activity in your App which automatically checks the current version of App on Play Store and Show Dialog if version does not match to force update

Comment: Thanks for reply my question. I want my app to auto update without user interaction so it's quite not useful for me. I can upload it to playstore but all the device have to use the wifi with private proxy for security so the device can't reach the playstore

Answer (score 0):

If your app is on google play 
you can use [upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader)

[image]

Comment: it says: 'On Android, this widget does nothing as there is no easy way to query the Google Play Store for metadata about an app.' so how does it work in android phone? I am confused.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload an apk to https://www.diawi.com/ and share a private link with your customers.